# What's the proper way to read/populate data buffers using message structs in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a program that deals char[] buffers to send/receive messages. Until now, this is how it has been handled:

```
#pramga pack(1)
struct messageType
{
    uint8_t data0:4;
    uint8_t data1:4;
    uint8_t data2;
    //etc...
};
#pragma pack()

void MyClass::processMessage(char* buf)
{
    // I already know buf is big enough to hold a messageType
    messageType* msg = reinterpret_cast<messageType*>(buf);

    //populate class member variables
    m_data0 = msg->data0;
    m_data1 = msg->data1;
    m_data2 = msg->data2;
    //etc  
}
```

Now from what I've gathered from reading around is that this is technically undefined behavior due to strict aliasing, and that `memcpy` should be used instead? What I don't quite understand is, what potential issues does copying `buf` byte for byte to `messageType msgNotPtr`, then reading from that `msgNotPtr`, actually avoid?

Regarding sending, instead of doing this:

```
void MyClass::sendMessage()
{
    char buf[max_tx_size];
    messageType* msg = reinterpret_cast<messageType*>(buf);

    msg->data0 = m_data0;
    //etc...
    send(buf);
}
```

I've read that I should be using `placement new` isntead, ala:

```
messageType* msg = new(buf) messageType;
```

If I do it this way, do I need to add additional cleanup, given that the struct `messageType` only contains POD types (such as manually firing the destructor)?

Edit: Now that I think about it, is `sendMessage` still undefined? Do I need to also swap out the last command with something like `send(reinterpret_cast<char*>(msg))` to make sure the compiler does not optimize out the call?

Comment: Given the code you provided, I'd say that you don't need to manually call the destructor since the `buf` is allocated on stack. You are dealing with POD so the only reason to call the destructor would be to free the allocated memory, and that is not required here.

Comment: @bialpio It's nothing to do with whether the buffer is on the stack or not. I don't know whether the destructor is required to be called when using placement new with a POD.

Comment: In the case of POD there is no reason to call a destructor - there is nothing to clean up (as in: no handles to close, no pointers to free, etc.) and the memory will be deallocated when the function returns because it was allocated on the stack. On the other hand: `char * buf = new char[sizeof(messageType)];` would require freeing the memory, and I'd expect that calling a destructor would free it.

Comment: @bialpio in that case, you'd use `delete[] buf`, no? I don't think that changes anything about manually calling a destructor.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the proper method to load a class instance from a uint8_t buffer is to load each member separately.

The class should know the positions of its members within the buffer and where and the size of any padding or reserved areas.

One of the issues with mapping structures to buffers is that the compiler can add space between members.  If you pack the structure to eliminate the padding, you slow down your program every time you access a member.

So, bite the performance on input and output by placing the members where you want them in the buffer (or extracting the members according to a specification).  The rest of the program can access the members the way the compiler aligned them.

This includes bit fields.

Also, by having the members loaded individually, the Endianess of the fields in the buffer can be account for much easier.

Comment: My question is more or less about how to extract the members from the buffer, according to a specification. I feel casting to a packed struct to do this is much simpler than the equivalent bitwise operations I'd have to do to get to members that are offset by 2, 4, etc.

Comment: I suppose I should note that my class members aren't packed, only the intermediate `messageType` is, which is used to populate my class variables.

Comment: So, you are going to implement one structure, packed, that matches the specification and another that is padded and used by the rest of the program?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. This is already implemented, but what I've read today about strict aliasing leads me to believe that my current implementation may be undefined. I'm trying to figure out if that's true, and the best way to resolve it if it is.